# C# - How to select distinct random records from datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, random, datatable

I am trying to fetch records from DataTable randomly with some limit. I am able to fetch the data randomly as follows -

```
 var r = new Random();
 var _randomSelection = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().OrderBy(rand => r.Next()).Take(limit);
```

But the values seems to be redundant. I want to get the unique values. So far I have tried **Distinct()** as -

```
var _randomSelection = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().OrderBy(rand => r.Next()).Take(limit).Distinct();
```

But that doesn't seems to be worked out. Can anybody please guide where am going wrong with this. Thanks.

Comment: Define unique first, which column(s) specifies the key(s) for the record? Currently `Distinct` can only compare DataRow references which all are different.

Comment: You should also change the order, first use `Distinct()` and then `Take` because otherwise you will often get less data than requested

Comment: @TimSchmelter am fetching the record of "id" column. I tested my query in SSMS and it it fetching unique records. But seems something up with the random function. That's why I'm getting duplicate values

Comment: @Adassko Tried changing the order but still no luck :(. Values are still redundant.

Comment: If `dt.Rows` contains unique records, your random ordering can't ever cause duplicates! You should be more specific in what output you expect and what you actually get; *doesn't seems to be worked out* is too vague.

Comment: @GertArnold I expected **Random Unique** records. But the records are being selected as random but they're not unique(even after using Distinct()) function.

Comment: Then you can't possibly fetch unique records as you claim. **Be more specific!**

Comment: @GertArnold Apologies. I am not understanding what exact description you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   DataTable returnVals = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "ColumnNameOnWhichYouWantDistinctRecords");
```

In `ToTable` method the first parameter specifies if you want `Distinct` records, the second specify by which column name we will make distinct.

After that if you want to take some number of it you can do

```
var result = returnVals.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(rand => r.Next()).Take(number);
```

Comment: I see no redundant record in DataTable. But when I try to fetch the records from DataTable **randomly**  that seems to have caused my data to be repetitive.

Comment: Add the order by part to second line.

Comment: How about using a "DISTINCT" keyword in the query itself? Just Curious!

Answer (score 0):

If you want unique records according to one column:

```
var distinctRows = from r in table.AsEnumerable()
                   let id = r.Field<int>("Id")
                   group r by id into idGroup
                   select idGroup.First();
```

If you want unique records according to multiple  columns, use an anonymous type:

```
var distinctRows = from r in table.AsEnumerable()
                   let keyCols = new { id=  r.Field<int>("Id"), col2 = r.Field<string>("Col2")}
                   group r by keyCols into keyGroup
                   select keyGroup.First();
```

if you want a dynamic way to compare all columns even if you don't know them:

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public class DataRowValuesComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
    {
        public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
        {
            if(ReferenceEquals(x, y))
                return true;
            if (x == null || y == null)
                return false;
            if (!ReferenceEquals(x.Table, y.Table))
                return false; // different tables
            foreach (DataColumn column in x.Table.Columns)
            {
                object v1 = x[column];
                object v2 = y[column];
                if (ReferenceEquals(v1, v2)) continue;
                if (v1 == null || v2 == null) return false;
                if (!v1.Equals(v2)) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return int.MinValue;
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = 19;
                foreach (DataColumn column in obj.Table.Columns)
                {
                    object value = obj[column];
                    hash = hash * 31 + (value?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
                }
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DataRow> DistinctValues(this IEnumerable<DataRow> rows)
    {
        return rows.Distinct(new DataRowValuesComparer());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var distinctRows = table.AsEnumerable().DistinctValues();
```